# How to find minimum of n sfixed array values using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I need to find the minimum of 5 s-fixed values, as I have an array of 5 values val3=[x1 x2 x3 x4 x5]
and I need to fill another array val33=[y1 y2 y3 y4 y5], while y1 is the minimum value of the array val3 except the value x1 and y2 is the minimum of val3 except x2, and so on.
I have tried the following lines:

```
TYPE T IS ARRAY (NATURAL RANGE <>) of sfixed(6 downto -5);
SIGNAL val3      :T(4 downto 0);
SIGNAL val33     :T(4 downto 0);
SIGNAL V_two :sfixed(6 DOWNTO -5);

for k in 0 to 4 loop
for l in 0 to 4 loop
V_two := val3(k);
val3(k) <= to_sfixed(32,6,-5);
if V_two < val3(l) then val33(k) <= V_two;
elsif V_two >= val3(l) then val33(k) <=val3(l);
end if;
end loop; 
end loop;
```

The problem is I always have V-two equal to 32 and not the indexed value from val3, so val33 is filled only with 32 values.

I don't know if there is a simple way to do this or where I have made the mistake
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: do you need this to synthesize? or testbench only?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I suggest you [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It would also be useful for other readers if you provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Assuming your code is inside a process, I get the feeling the problem here might come down to a signal vs variable problem. You appear to assign the value `val3(k)` before then checking the value `val3(l)` from the same array, which wll be using the old value, because it is a signal. But it is hard to tell when the code is not in context. Please provide a MCVE

Comment: You must have done some copy/paste errors, because V_two is a signal but you assign it with ":=" which is not possible and leads to a compile error.

Comment: Indeed I need it to synthesize Russel

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing Tricky and Matthias, I was trying the V_two as a variable and missed changing the assignment, the code is still the same. val3(k) assignment should be changed to "<=".   I can share the codes if that helps